# Automatic e-mail extraction in Java

Tags: java, text-extraction, email-address

How can I scan for potential e-mail addresses in a text file using Java?

Comment: Please don't repost, especially when the question is a bad one. You've asked this question twice and a similar one before that -- don't ask what you have to do, **ask about what you don't understand**.

Comment: Read the text file line by line and check each line red by applying the RegEx on it.

Comment: @Mudassir maybe she can use this regex http://www.ex-parrot.com/pdw/Mail-RFC822-Address.html :D

Answer (score 0):

read file and use regex to match your pattern with any possible email address.

Comment: read the complete file line by line. Match each line with the regex. if there is any match, extract it or do whatever you need to fulfil your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

Use regular expressions. This is the one I have used.

(([\w-]+.)+[\w-]+|([a-zA-Z]{1}|[\w-]{2,}))
           ((([0-1]?[0-9]{1,2}|25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]).([0-1]?[0-9]{1,2}|25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]).
             ([0-1]?[0-9]{1,2}|25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]).([0-1]?[0-9]{1,2}|25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9])){1}|
           ([a-zA-Z]+[\w-]+.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,4})|^((+\d{1,3}(-| )?(?\d)?(-| )?\d{1,5})
           |((?\d{2,6})?))(-| )?(\d{3,4})(-| )?(\d{4})(( x| ext)\d{1,5}){0,1}